# stm32f303x DAC performance

Tags: stm32

I want to generate a modified sine wave from a lookup table, with a fundamental frequency of around 125kHz. I am assuming I can DMA a 12 bit sample every 200nS, so sending it around 40 per cycle.
I have got a DAC o/p work, BUT I am not getting a clean full scale signal ie 4095 != 3V. It peaks at around 2V
I have tried feeding it a square wave at low frequency ie 0, 4095...4095,0...
The problem appears to be a very slow rise time - around 2uS to go from 0V to 3V. Almost like it is driving into a heavy capacitative load.
Is this normal? Any suggestions?

Comment: I am using the STM32F303x DISCOVERY board

Answer (score 1):

The problem (or part of it) seems to be me not enabling a buffered output. This line:

DAC_InitStructure.DAC_OutputBuffer = DAC_OutputBuffer_Enable;

sharpens the output considerably